# How to Tell if Neo4j Embedded Database Is Newly Created

Tags: clojure, neo4j

I have a Clojure application using Neo4j in embedded mode.  I call (`new GraphDatabaseFactory).newEmbeddedDatabase` with a new path.  How can I tell if the resulting `GraphDatabaseService` was newly created / empty?

Bonus question:  if it wasn't newly created, how can I read metadata in the database to tell what version of my system it was built with?  If someone accidentally passes in a path to a valid Neo4j database that wasn't created with my application, I want to throw an `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I don't know clojure.

Programmatically, I do not see a way to determine this, but you can implement this by checking if the directory exists prior to making the call to the `GraphDatabaseFactory`.

As for the meta data, you can do this if you cast the `GraphDatabaseService` to an `InternalAbstractGraphDatabase` and perform a `getConfig()` on it. This will allow you access to the `Config` class, which has a property map that contains arguments that can show you the version, as well as other things.